# How to explain inconsistencies between visualvm cpu sample and snapshot created from it?

Tags: performance, profiling, visualvm

I've used cpu sampler of visualvm to record a behavior of my application for the purpose of finding a performance bottleneck. I can see some interesting results in live hotspots view, but when i take a snapshot of from the live view for later work, hotspots in that snapshot is absolutely different. This picture explains it pretty well: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=auhx0j&s=6

How is this inconsistency possible? Maybe I don't understand what live view and snapshot is, can someone clarify it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tool, but clearly the program is doing I/O, so CPU time is meaningless. I suggest getting familiar with the [*issues in profiling*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but relevance of those values are completely different question which I'll investigate later, but first I have to solve the mystery of those values being different in the mentioned views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for the reasoning why there are inconsistencies between the sampler and snapshot hot spots. Since I couldn't find an explanation here nor anywhere else I tried to figure it out myself.

**tl;dr**

It is most probable a bug in the visualization of the snapshot view because it seems to not fully respect the exclusion packages like `sun.*` and so on which are set by default when starting the sampler.

**How did I came to my conclusion?**

Well, I played with different package exclusion settings turning all off, some on and so forth and always looking at the sampler and snapshot view comparing them.
Although I exclude the `java.*, sun.*` packages they still show up in the snapshot view but not in the sampler view. What I still don't get either is when I remove all package exclusions then snapshot and sampler views are identical what everybody would expect regardless of which packages are excluded.

So far my two cents. Happy sampling!

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange. If you can provide steps how to reproduce it, I will be happy to investigate it.

Comment: Sorry, reproducing this is almost impossible, since it has been detected on preproduction environment of application bigger than mother of my worst enemy:-).